# ArcPad Studio default values only show up in ArcPad when I make new points

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcpad, default, default-value

I am using ArcPad to do a habitat inventory (default value= "N/A") and invasive species survey (default value= "Absent") on a grid of preset points (the points are a shapefile). The default values only appear in my drop down boxes in ArcPad if I drop a new point onto the landscape, they won't appear when I click on a point from my preexisting grid of survey points.

The text is in quotes (such as "N/A") and I put it in the value tab in control properties on ArcPad Studio. Why won't it show up for my existing points?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that you needed to pre-populate the cells in the attribute table with the default value AND set the same phrase as the default in ArcPad Studio.